# What is it called when you hash a URL params and map it to the database?

Tags: django, url, hash

Hi I'm working with Django as my backend and I've been trying to search up this term but I can't seem to find it.

For example Spotify has a URL for a song https://open.spotify.com/track/0feI2qZLlaapheeJeznYwZ

I'm guessing the hashed ID maps to one of the autogenerated ID's.

What would I search up to implement this in my app ?

Any references will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's just as likely that it's just a random string, so perhaps you can search 'generate random secure string in Django'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often UUID is used:
`https://example.com/users/ab45765d-9092-4cbd-8402-a9b788c08d6a/`

there is Django.models.UUIDField: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

Use it for your `id`/`pk` model field and your `detail` links  will be with this uuid field instead of `integers` or `slug`.